# Condition variables with Qt network requests

Tags: qt, c++11, condition-variable, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

I have an app in which I do some "synchronous-like" calls with Qt's QNetwork* classes. The code which has been adapted from various sources online and looks something like:

```
QNetworkRequest request("http://www.somedomain.com");
QNetworkReply* pReply = _manager->get(request); 

// A not-so-great-solution to wait for the request, but works
QEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(pReply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()), Qt::DirectConnection);
loop.exec(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);

// Now the pReply object has what I want, yay!
```

I implemented this knowing that this was a hack. I started wondering if I could instead use C++'s condition variables to achieve something similar. My code to attempt this looks something like:

```
QNetworkRequest request("http://www.somedomain.com");
QNetworkReply* pReply = _manager->get(request);

QObject::connect(pReply, &QNetworkReply::finished,
    [this]()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_requestMutex);
        _requestCV.notify_one();
    });

std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_requestMutex);
_requestCV.wait(lock, [this, pReply]()
{
    return pReply->isFinished();
});
```

This is my first time experimenting with condition variables, so I'm not entirely sure I'm using them correctly (with `_requestCV` of course being the condition variable in this example). But what really has me baffled is that the QNetworkReply::finished lambda never executes. In the first example, the finished() event seems to trigger nearly right away and the QNetworkReply has everything I'd expect. Why does the pReply's finished() event never get called in the second example?

Note: I understand that many people feel strongly about synchronous network calls, especially with Qt's model which is obviously designed to be used asynchronously. However, that's not what I'm interested in discussing with this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> But what really has me baffled is that the QNetworkReply::finished
>   lambda never executes.

You're blocking the event loop of your thread, and that's this event loop that is supposed to deliver your `finished`signal. No event loop, no signal.

> Note: I understand that many people feel strongly about synchronous
>   network calls, especially with Qt's model which is obviously designed
>   to be used asynchronously.

Well, you've given a good example of the reasons why people feel that way.

Comment: Aren't I only blocking on the current thread? If this code itself is executed on a different thread would the event loop still be blocked?

Comment: @Addy It looks like you block the same thread, where you call QNetworkAccessManager::get(), so either you block its thread, or you call get from different thread (and I don't think it's thread safe...).

Comment: @Addy "If this code itself is executed on a different thread would the event loop still be blocked? "* Each thread has its event loop, but that's the point: you're blocking the loop that's supposed to deliver your signal.

Comment: @Addy OK - I'll add that bit in the answer to clarify